# python 3 function with one argument returning list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, function

how the 're' function should look like if it must receive just one argument 's' and must return a list with the numbers (integers) from 1 to 12 incl. (for example)?

so the result in the interactive console have to be:

```
>>> re(12)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: There is a builtin that handles this

Comment: You're going to want to use a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you used `def` incorrectly, if you want to define you have to enter `:` and define function in additional indentation below, or if you want to use function, you have to remove `def`.

Python has built-in [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) immutable sequence type, which takes one to three arguments **start**, **stop** and **step**, in this case we only will use first two. However to get list we also need to use another built-in, which is mutable sequence type - [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), you can read more about lists in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). We will use list() as the type constructor: `list()` or `list(iterable)` as specified in built-in types page:

> Lists may be constructed in several ways:
>
> ```
> Using a pair of square brackets to denote the empty list: []
> Using square brackets, separating items with commas: [a], [a, b, c]
> Using a list comprehension: [x for x in iterable]
> Using the type constructor: list() or list(iterable)
> ```
>
> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same
>   order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a
>   container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable
>   is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to
>   iterable[:]. For example, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and
>   list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, the
>   constructor creates a new empty list, [].

Now that we understand how `list()` works, we can go back to `range()` usage:

> - The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in int or any object that implements the **index** special
>     method). If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the
>     start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If step is zero,
>     ValueError is raised.
> - For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
> - For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints
>     are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.
> - A range object will be empty if r[0] does not meet the value constraint. Ranges do support negative indices, but these are
>     interpreted as indexing from the end of the sequence determined by the
>     positive indices.
> - Ranges containing absolute values larger than sys.maxsize are permitted but some features (such as len()) may raise OverflowError.
>
> **Range examples:**
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> list(range(10))
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> >>> list(range(1, 11))
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
> >>> list(range(0, 30, 5))
> [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
> >>> list(range(0, 10, 3))
> [0, 3, 6, 9]
> >>> list(range(0, -10, -1))
> [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
> >>> list(range(0))
> []
> >>> list(range(1, 0))
> []
> ```
>
> Ranges implement all of the common sequence operations except concatenation and repetition (due to the fact that range objects can
>   only represent sequences that follow a strict pattern and repetition
>   and concatenation will usually violate that pattern).
>
> - **start**:
>     The value of the start parameter (or 0 if the parameter was not supplied)
> - **stop**:
>     The value of the stop parameter
> - **step**:
>     The value of the step parameter (or 1 if the parameter was not supplied)

Many other operations also produce lists, including the sorted() built-in.

The answer to your question looks like that:

```
def re(ending_number):
    return list(range(1, ending_number + 1))

list_of_twelve = re(12) # list_of_twelve will contain [1, 2, ..., 12]
```

Comment: @ccsann If I solved your problem you should mark question as answered.

Comment: @ccsann https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @ccsann oh, and there is official guide about [how to react to answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would avoid using "re" as a function name, since re is also a python library for regex expressions.
2. Lycopersicum's answer does a good job of explaining range(), which is the fastest and most straight-forward way of approaching your problem. In general, it is best to use Python's built-in functions, that's because it will use Python's compiled C code rather than slower Python code.

I just thought I'd share a little bit about why you should use Range().

So, there are other ways to generate a list of numbers.  First generate a list directly using a loop.

```
def listOfNumbers (number):
  start = 1
  listOf = []
  while (start <= number):
    listOf.append(start)
    start = start + 1
    return listOf
```

In this case, you simply use `listOfNumbers(12)` and you will get a list of numbers.  However, this stores a list in memory and is slow, so not good for very large numbers.

On the other hand, you could use a generator (which is very much like range()).  A generator does not store data in a list.  Instead, it just "yields" numbers one at a time until the code stops.  It's much faster:

```
def generatorOfNumbers (number):
 start = 1
 while start <= number:
   yield start
   start += 1
```

Then you can call it one of two ways to produce a list:

```
def listFromGenerator1 (number):
  return [x for x in generatorOfNumbers(number)]

def listFromGenerator2 (number):
  return list(generatorOfNumbers (number))
```

When I time these approaches I get.

```
timed(listOfNumbers) # time for list of 10000
... 
Elapsed Time: 2.16007232666
Elapsed Time: 1.32894515991
Elapsed Time: 2.09093093872
Elapsed Time: 1.99699401855
Elapsed Time: 3.2000541687

...   timed(listFromGenerator1)
... 
Elapsed Time: 1.33109092712
Elapsed Time: 1.30605697632
Elapsed Time: 1.93309783936
Elapsed Time: 1.79386138916
Elapsed Time: 1.90401077271

...   timed(listFromGenerator2)
... 
Elapsed Time: 0.869989395142
Elapsed Time: 1.08408927917
Elapsed Time: 1.65319442749
Elapsed Time: 1.53398513794
Elapsed Time: 1.36089324951

...   timed(listFromRange)  # Lycopersicum's approach
... 
Elapsed Time: 0.346899032593
Elapsed Time: 0.284194946289
Elapsed Time: 0.282049179077
Elapsed Time: 0.295877456665
Elapsed Time: 0.303983688354
```

In conclusion, *always* use built-in functions whenever possible rather than trying to build your own.  That includes the (slight) preference for list() vs a list comprehension.